# Why is .text always empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried using getText() [Referencing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-text-from-selenium-element-webelement-object), but when I use that method I always get the error `"WebElement object has no attribute getText()"`. I found .`text` through a YouTube video but I'm not getting results from it either. Any thoughts?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driverPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)


driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get ('https://shop.pricechopper.com/search?search_term=lettuce')

pageSource = driver.page_source

search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name ("css-dr3s47")
print (search[0].text)



driver.quit()
```

Comment: Instead of `.text` try with `.get_attribute("innerText")`. And see if that works.

Comment: you could also try to emulate the api request rather than scraping

Comment: thanks for the replies, pretty much all the solutions suggested worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **Selenium with Python**, so correct method is `.text`

`.getText()` is for **Selenium-Java Bindings**.

The reason why are you getting null is cause elements are not rendered properly and you are trying to interact with them resulting in null.

Please use **Explicit wait** or `time.sleep()` which is worst case to get rid of this issue.

Also, there's a pop window that we will have to click on close web element, so that `css-dr3s47` will be available to Selenium view port.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://shop.pricechopper.com/search?search_term=lettuce")
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@ng-click='processModalCloseClick()']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on modal pop up closer button')
except:
    pass

search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name ("css-dr3s47")
print (search[0].text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

getText returns elements with rendered size more than 0 * 0 , so if element is not displayed of has size zero , then it wont return anything .

Two things you could do is :

1. scroll to the element before getting text

> ```
>  Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);
>   // Performs mouse move action onto the element
>   actionProvider.moveToElement(search[0]).build().perform();
>   print(search[0].text)
> ```

2. Use textCOntent

Text content doesn't check for display or size , it just gives content

```
    print(search[0].get_attribute("textContent"))
```